# Android Asset Manager unable to load wav file assets from the assets directory

Tags: java, android, android-assets, android-assetmanager

I am have a few wav files that I want to load with the help of Android's asset manager. Unfortunately, everytime I try to do so, I get the following error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: audio-file.wav not found

I would like to add the following assets to the Android sound pool.

This is the image of my application set up.

[Application IDE Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVA9e.png)

My code

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

  @LayoutRes
  protected int getLayoutRes() {
    return R.layout.activity_fragment;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutRes());

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
      fragment = new MyActivityFragment();
      fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }
  }

}
```

Fragment

```
    public class MyActivityFragment extends Fragment {

       private static final String TAG = "MyFragment";
       private static final String SOUNDS_FOLDER = "sample_sounds";
       private static final int MAX_SOUNDS = 5;


    private final AssetManager mAssetManager;

      private final List<Integer> sounds = new ArrayList<>();
      private SoundPool mSoundPool; 

      @Override
      public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        this.mAssetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
        this.loadAssets();
        mSoundPool = this.buildSoundPool();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mSoundPool.release();
      }


  private SoundPool buildSoundPool() {
    SoundPool.Builder builder = new SoundPool.Builder();
    builder.setMaxStreams(MAX_SOUNDS);
    builder.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build());
    return builder.build();
  }

  private void loadAssets() {
    try {
      String[] soundNames = mAssetManager.list(SOUNDS_FOLDER);
      for (String soundName : soundNames) {
        sounds.add(load(soundName));
      }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Could not list assets");
    }
  }

   private int load(String soundName) throws IOException {
      AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssetManager.openFd(soundName);
      int soundId = mSoundPool.load(afd, 1);
      return soundId;
   }
}
```

This method raises a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
private int load(String soundName) throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssetManager.openFd(soundName);
    int soundId = mSoundPool.load(afd, 1);
    return soundId;
  }
```

This line precisely

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssetManager.openFd(soundName);
```

I have gone through the other posts related to this issue, but the most recent post is at least 3 years old. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, `list()` returns the names of the items in the asset directory. It does not return the *paths* of those items.

Try replacing:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssetManager.openFd(soundName);
```

with:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssetManager.openFd(SOUND_FOLDER+"/"+soundName);
```